# Cypress Error (Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat)

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner

When I am trying to Run Cypress Test Runner following error is coming
**Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat**

**Cypress Version**

Cypress package version: 9.5.1
Cypress binary version: 9.5.1
Electron version: 15.3.4
Bundled Node version:
16.5.0

Following are the configuration:-

1. Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "cypressautomationproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^9.5.1",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mochawesome": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cucumber": "^7.0.0-rc.0",
    "run": "^1.4.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "description": "",
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
}
```

2. Cypress.json

```js
{
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 6000,
  "pageLoadTimeout": 20000,
  "reporter":"mochawesome",
  "modifyObstructiveCode": true,
 "experimentalSourceRewriting":true,
 "chromeWebSecurity": true,
 
 "testFiles": ["**/*.feature","**/*.js"],
  "projectId": "jyfuej",
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true,
    "cucumberJson": {
      "generate": true,
      "outputFolder": "cypress/cucumber-json",
      "filePrefix": "",
      "fileSuffix": ".cucumber"
    }
  }
  }
```

---

Not able to Identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules

Just delete `package-lock.json` file and then install packages you want with `npm install` . All will work.

`rm -rf node_modules`

`rm package-lock.json`

`npm install`

If the issue still persists check if you have a global version of any of the packages installed. This can happen if you have a global version of a package that clashes with a local version of a package.

And another thing,
It may be a problem with the cache, try to verify the cache.

`npm cache verify`

If this due to npm cache problems. Run

`npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache`

Comment: I have tried all the above option as suggested by you still same error is coming

Comment: @Ajay have you got the solution? I am facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes. You have to Update the Cypress Version. For Me this work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while scripting below import gets added by mistake in auto suggestion in stepdefination file.

```
import { text } from "stream/consumers";
```

Remove this & script will work.