# Stream module error when using Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

**Problem**
When trying to build my bundle.js file, I get the following:

```txt
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\[filepath&filename]\stream'
    required by C:\[filepath]\script.js
```

My package.json file is as follows:

```json
{
  "name": "[projectName]",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify script.js -o bundle.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^17.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "stream-consumers": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

High level, the code I'm trying to run is as follows:

```js
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js'); 
const { json } = require('stream/consumers');

function doSomething() {

}
doSomething();
```

**What I've tried**
I've tried a number of different recommended ways to fix this, including:

- Adding './' - as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65499459/20331138) which gives 'Cannot find module'
- Deleting package-lock.json file and then installing the packages I wanted to install - as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71419452/20331138)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74235083/20331138) unblocked the issue for me.

It turned out that:

```js
const { json } = require('stream/consumers');
```

wasn't required, so when I commented it out, it seemed to resolve the issue...